# How do I check for nulls and empty string for a needle in a haystack?

Tags: java

Situation: I am coming across a lot of checks in my code. And I would like to know of a way in which I can reduce them.

```
if(needle!=null && haystack!=null)
{
  if(needle.length()==0)
   return true;
  else
  {
   if(haystack.length()==0)
   return false;
   else
   {
     // Do 2 for loops to check character by character comparison in a substring  
   }
 }

}
else 
 return false;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a different code style would increase the readability of your code and reduce the amount of nested `if` statements for all of your checks.:

```
if (needle == null || haystack == null || haystack.isEmpty())
    return false;

if (needle.isEmpty())
    return true;

// compare strings here and return result.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class for the strings, then add a function like isValid() to them that checks if the length == 0.  Use a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) that always returns false on isValid() to eliminate the null checks.

If you can create classes that you tell what to do, rather than passing strings that have to be null checked throughout your code, you will get more resuseable results:

```
    class Haystack {
    private static final Haystack NULL_HAYSTACK = new Haystack("");
    private final String value;

    public Haystack(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean containsNeedle(String needle) {
        return needle != null && value.contains(needle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consolidate that logic into a single method on a singleton 'StringFunctions' class and update the usages to use the common method as you encounter them.